# Is there an easy way to move the wp_admin_bar to my own location?

Tags: admin-bar

I want to remove the admin bar from the top of the page and actually place it into a custom location within my theme.

Question:

1. How would I call wp_admin_bar() inside a custom div.

I would also need to remove the built in css, so that I can apply my own.

*I already have a filter to do this part.

Reasons:

My theme is being built to be ipad/iphone friendly. I want the admin bar to be 'fixed' to the top of the screen.

The problem is that mobile safari does not accept position:fixed, which requires a js workaround, which I have already solved.

My theme already has a fixed header which is ipad ready. If I can call the wp_admin_bar() and place that within this 'special' div, then the problem is solved.

*thanks to other people helping me on this forum, I have managed to place the built in wp_menu() into the admin bar, which is really cool. With that functionality added to the admin bar, I now have a really awesome nav bar by combining its built in functionality with custom menus.

Comment: You can probably move the DOM nodes with Javascript on the client side. However, I'll try to find a solution that just outputs the HTML in another place.

Comment: Thanks Jan. Yeah it would be really nice to just place wp_admin_bar() in the middle of the div where I want to place the bar and then apply my own styling instead of using the built in styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to output the admin bar at a different location, but [the included Javascript always moves the bar to the `body` element](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.dev.js#L124) - probably to make it work when a theme has not closed all HTML elements at the end of the page.

So if you want to move it somewhere else, you must do this *after* the standard script moved it to the body. I did this by loading the script in the footer, after the admin bar:

```
function wpse15444_wp_print_scripts()
{
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse-15444', plugins_url( 'wpse-15444.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    }
}

// wpse-15444.js
jQuery( window ).load( function() {
    jQuery( '#wpadminbar' ).appendTo( jQuery( '#wpse15444-admin-bar-container' ) );
} );
```

Because the bar normally has `position: fixed` you won't see it move, so make it `position: absolute` in your own stylesheet.

By adding the `wpse1544-admin-bar-container` in the `#header` of the Twenty Ten theme, I got the following result:

[image: Admin bar in header instead of top of page]

Comment: You are the man! LOL.. solution worked perfectly, but then you knew that already.

Answer (score 1):

The current admin bar uses `position:fixed` and is found in admin-bar.css. I removed that style because I prefer the admin bar on the bottom when debugging as it often covers up output.

It seems for the most part the `#wpadminbar` ID can be fully styled and over ridden using `!important.`

The alternative and better option is to deregister_style and register your own.

You need to find in the code where admin-bar.css is enqueued, then add a custom function that hooks into it and turn it off, for instance if the enqueue style function is called wp-pagenavi.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'my_deregister_styles', 100 );

function my_deregister_styles() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'wp-pagenavi' );
}
```

Then you can enqueue your own style using:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'myStyleSheets');
```

- after a quick look I'm not sure it is possible to de-register the admin-bar.css