# Move WP Admin Bar

Tags: wp-admin, navigation

I am trying to move the WP Admin bar on the front end to below my themes main header navigation, as well as make it the same width.

I am using the GeneratePress theme and am getting support from them to achieve this, however we’re stuck.

Here’s what they said,
“ I just dug through the core WordPress code for the admin bar hoping to find a way to unhook the current position and move it somewhere else, but I came up empty.

Basically, we need to unhook the bar from the current position and hook it into a different action.”

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: I would just update the CSS. You don't need to change the action to change the position.

Comment: found an old topic related to your question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15444/is-there-an-easy-way-to-move-the-wp-admin-bar-to-my-own-location (not tested)

Answer (score 5):

The admin bar [is hooked to `wp_footer`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L539). So …

```
remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 0 );
```

… will remove it from there. And then you can register it for a custom hook with:

```
add_action( 'my_custom_hook', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 );
```

You still have to overwrite [the CSS](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3/src/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.css) in your stylesheet, but that should be fairly simple.

Oh, and welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! :)

Comment: Thank you. I am still unfortunately not able to get it to work. This is the code that the theme developer gave me to try:

remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 0 );
add_action( 'generate_after_header', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 20 ); 

When I put it in my themes functions.php file. It does nothing. It doesn't even remove the WP Bar. However, when I use this code:

function hide_admin_bar(){ return false; }
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'hide_admin_bar' );

It successfully removes the WP bar. Now I need to find a way to add the WP bar below the theme's header. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you read the full answer? You need to also override its CSS so that it doesn't float.

Comment: as far as I understand, the adminbar gets loaded via jQuery into its location just inside the body tag; unhooking the function from 'wp_footer' and hooking it into a different location within the theme would not change that. using just CSS to change from 'fixed' to 'absolute' and to new coordinates would be quite challenging in a responsive theme.